# "Unrecognized expression '$addFields'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am getting an error :

> "Unrecognized expression '$addFields'"

When I am trying to calculate the average of fields from an array using MongoDB aggregation framework.

Can some one help me to understand what is wrong in the below code snippet.

My DB version is 3.4.5

```
"doctor": {

        "$map": {
            "input": "$$procedure.doctor",
            "as": "doctor",
            "in": {
                "$cond": [//specify the filter for doctor
                    {
                        "$eq": ["$$doctor.activeFlag", "Y"]
                    },
                    {
                        "doctorName": "$$doctor.doctorName", 

                        "DoctorUserRating": {

                            "$map": {
                                "input": "$$doctor.DoctorUserRating",
                                "as": "docUserRate",
                                "in": {
                                    "$cond": [//specify the filter for user rating
                                    {},
                                    {
                                     //Calculate the average of userRating from array
                                        "$addFields": {
                                            "avarageDocRating": {
                                                "$divide": [
                                                    { // expression returns total
                                                        "$reduce": {
                                                            "input": "$$docUserRate",
                                                            "initialValue": 0,
                                                            "in": { "$add": ["$$value", "$$this.userRating"] }
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    { // expression returns ratings count
                                                        "$cond": [
                                                            { "$ne": [{ "$size": "$$docUserRate" }, 0] },
                                                            { "$size": "$$docUserRate" },
                                                            1
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        },

                                    //////////////////////
                                        },
                                        false
                                    ],
                                },//"in": {
                            },//"$map": {
                        },//"DoctorUserRating": {          
                    },
                    false
                ],
            },//"in": {
        },//"$map": {
    },//"doctor":
```

My Model is

```
hospitalName: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
hospitalID: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true, dropDups: true }, 
serviceActiveFlag: { type: String, required: true, enum: ['Y', 'N'] },//new    
Treatment: [{        
    procedureid: { type: Number },

    costUpperBound: { type: Number, required: true },                

    doctor: [{
        doctorId: { type: Number},
        doctorName: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },                    
        DoctorUserRating:[ {  
            userRating:{type: Number, required: true, //To get default rating for cost api
                min: [1, 'The value of path `{PATH}` ({VALUE}) is beneath the limit ({MIN}).'],
                max: [5, 'The value of path `{PATH}` ({VALUE}) exceeds the limit ({MAX}).']                                       
            },
            userId: { type: String, required: false, trim: true},
        }],
   }],
}],
updated_at: { type: D
```

ate, required: true, default: Date.now }

Comment: $addFields is a toplevel agg function; it cannot be used inside $map.  Please post a representative doc or two and describe in text specifically what you're trying to average in what array and I'm sure we'll have a solution for you.

Comment: Thanks.I have updated model in the question.Basically i am creating an api which retrives hospitalName,costUpperBound,doctorName and average of DoctorUserRating from my db.Hope it gives enough information for you to provide a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution -

```
"DoctorUserRating": {

"$map": {
    "input": "$$doctor.DoctorUserRating",
    "as": "docUserRate",
    "in": {
        "$cond": [//specify the filter for user rating
        {},
        {
         "averageDocRate": { "$avg": "$$docUserRate.userRating" }
        },
 }
```

Comment: "OK."  I might suggest you look at the MongoDB $filter function.   Your use of $map seems like $filter might be a much more convenient alternative.